# PHP loop through array with condition

Tags: php, loops

I have a loop which i made like this:

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
foreach ($arr as &$value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

My loop result shows this:

```
1234567
```

I would like this to only show the numbers 1 to 4.
And when it reaches 4 it should add a break and continue with 5671.

So an example is:

```
1234<br>
5671<br>
2345<br>
6712<br>
```

I have to make this but I have no idea where to start, all hints/tips are very welcome or comment any direction I should Google.

Comment: How many times do you need it to loop through that array?

Comment: Google `if statements`.

Comment: @FunkDoc only 5 times

Comment: @FunkDoc and then start over

Comment: `wordwrap(join($a),4,'<br>',1)` #UnnecessaryCodeGolf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is more universal function- you can pass an array as argument, and amount of elements you want to display.

```
<?php

$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);

function getFirstValues(&$array, $amount){
    for($i=0; $i<$amount; $i++){
        echo $array[0];
        array_push($array, array_shift($array));
    }
    echo "<br />";
}

getFirstValues($array, 4);
getFirstValues($array, 4);
getFirstValues($array, 4);
getFirstValues($array, 4);


?>
```

The result is:
1234
5671
2345
6712

Answer (score 2):

This produces the exact results you want

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
$k=0;
for($i=1;$i<=5;++$i){
  foreach ($arr as &$value) {
    ++$k;
     echo $value;
     if($k %4 == 0) {
    echo '<br />';
   $k=0;
}
}
}
```

Comment: hey it works perfect but it repeats the process 9 times and the 9th result is only 3 numbers long :P

Comment: @Kevin.a Then you need to state more clearly what the exact expected output is. "Only 5 times" and "and then start over", as you commented earlier, is confusing. Please, properly formulate your exact problem and exact expected outcome.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [array_chunk()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-chunk.php)

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13);
$chunks = array_chunk($arr, 4);
foreach ($chunks as $array) {
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        echo $value;
    }
    echo "<br />";
}
```

The output is:

```
1234
5678
9101112
13
```